# Displaying and Updating Annotations through Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, mapkit, firebase-realtime-database, mkannotation

I have the following Firebase Database structure:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "TzDyIOXukcVYFr8HEBC5Y9KeOyJ2" : {
      "Contact Number" : "",
      "Name" : "",
      "User Email" : "test@test.com"
    },
    "xqKdv6hN1wSGplvKh3sYuutFmwz2" : {
      "Contact Number" : "",
      "Name" : "",
      "User Email" : “test2@test.com”
    }
  },
  "buildings-list" : {
    "-KTd0ZU-pJHYBs282RfI" : {
      "addedByUser" : "TzDyIOXukcVYFr8HEBC5Y9KeOyJ2",
      "content" : "Post 1",
      "cost" : "5000",
      "duration" : "Annually",
      "latitude" : "25.2003331668539",
      "longitude" : "55.2563433525882",
      "number" : "1234567890",
      "timestamp" : "Sun 09 Oct"
    }
  }
}
```

I have an .observe reference to the Firebase database which adds markers to a map based on the latitude and longitude.

```
func displayAllMarkers() {

        dbRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

            let latitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["latitude"] as! String!
            let latitudeDouble = Double(latitude!)
            let longitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["longitude"] as! String!
            let longitudeDouble = Double(longitude!)
            let markerTitle = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["content"] as! String!
            let durationTitle = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["duration"] as! String!
            let costTitle = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["cost"] as! String!
            let timestamp = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["timestamp"] as! String!
            self.telephoneNumber = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["number"] as! String!

            let annotation = myAnnotationView(title: markerTitle!.capitalized, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitudeDouble!, longitude: longitudeDouble!), duration: durationTitle!, cost: costTitle!, info: "", timestamp: timestamp!, contactNumber: self.telephoneNumber!)
            //my annotationView is my custom class for annotations.
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation as MKAnnotation)


            })}
```

This successfully adds the markers to the map however when a child is deleted the markers are not updating/being removed from the map.  Do I need to add the for loop?... any help appreciated.

UPDATE: I have minimised the code by using the struct I have existing.

```
func getMarkers() {

    dbRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for buildings in snapshot.children {

            let buildingsObject = Buildings (snapshot: buildings as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            print(buildingsObject)

            let latDouble = Double(buildingsObject.latitude!)
            let lonDouble = Double(buildingsObject.longitude!)

            let annotation = myAnnotationView.init(title: buildingsObject.content, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: latDouble!, longitude: lonDouble!), duration: buildingsObject.duration, cost: buildingsObject.cost, info: "", timestamp: buildingsObject.timestamp, contactNumber: buildingsObject.number)

            print(snapshot)

            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation as MKAnnotation)

        }})}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

CMD+CLICK on the **`.childAdded`** and you will be directed to `FIRDataEventType` class documentation.

```
case childAdded // 0, fired when a new child node is added to a location

case childRemoved // 1, fired when a child node is removed from a location

case childChanged // 2, fired when a child node at a location changes

case childMoved // 3, fired when a child node moves relative to the other child nodes at a location

case value // 4, fired when any data changes at a location and, recursively, any children
```

Your options:-

- So if you want to listen to the location for if the child is deleted your eventType should be of **`.childRemoved`**
- But if you want to avoid loading another thread for **`.childRemoved`** (Which might increase your app's memory consumption) just use **`.value`** instead of either of those for the eventType. But the entire snapshot will be loaded so don't forget to loop over all the snap's and then add the annotation.
- Using **`.value`** will increase your **bandwidth** consumption which is limited. So a better approach would be to create a struct and add your annotation to an array of that type struct. And display your annotation from that Array. Whenever an annotation is added or deleted, do the same to your Array and your firebase database accordingly.

Comment: Im using this .observe method to place the markers on the map.  If I use .childRemoved it will not show the annotations on the map.  From what you're saying I will need 2 methods 1. place markers on the map 2. listen for removed markers? correct me if I'm wrong?...

Comment: No That's right. I did explain every possible combination that you can use... Just check my answer Accept and upvote this as answer if it solves your issue :) Happy Coding

Comment: @DavidLintin: you will indeed need a callback for each event that you want to respond to. So in your case that is likely `.childAdded` (which you already have), `.childChanged` and `.childRemoved` (which you'll need to add).

Comment: @Dravidian I already have a struct to which I believe I have followed your advice and am using that in the observe method please see my updated code:

Comment: @Dravidian this looks much better however, I am still not getting the annotations to update i.e. be removed/added when necessary.